# iframe variables in php

Tags: php

I've got an iframe that is sending variables in the url.  Problem is I've got 2 variables that is being send in the url, when I echo the first variable, it also displays the value of the 2nd variable:

**PAGE1**

```
<?php
$tid = $_SESSION['tid'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
echo "<IFRAME SRC='timer.php?tid=$tid?userid=$userid' WIDTH='500' HEIGHT='500' frameborder='0'></IFRAME>";
```

**TIMER.PHP**

```
session_start();
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
echo "tid:";
echo $tid;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
tid:8?userid=999
```

***The output should only be tid:8*** why the ?userid=999

Comment: Infact, it appears you are using a session to store the value of `tid` so instead of using `GET` why not just call `$_SESSION['tid']` on the timer page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL should be `timer.php?tid=$tid&userid=$userid` notice I replaced the second `?` with a `&`. You use a `?` to separate the variables from the rest of the URL, and the `&` to separate the variables from eachother.

Answer (score 2):

Well for one you're doing the GET parameters wrong, for each new parameter it should be split with a `&` not a `?` the question mark should only be used after the file name.

Wrong: `timer.php?tid=$tid?userid=$userid`

Right: `timer.php?tid=$tid&userid=$userid`

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace ? with &:
`tid=$tid&userid=$userid`

Answer (score 1):

Use & to seperate query string variables.

```
<?php
$tid = $_SESSION['tid'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
echo "<IFRAME SRC='timer.php?tid=$tid&userid=$userid' WIDTH='500' HEIGHT='500' frameborder='0'></IFRAME>";
```

The question mark just marks the beginning of the query string.